# What is the sigma algebra generated by $\tau$ in counter-example of informational content?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, set-theory

It would seem that finer sigma algebras would contain more information, but [here](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Efede/published/dubra-echenique-mbility.pdf) the following counter-example is given:

> Let the state of the world be a real number between $0$ and $1,$ so the set
> of possible states is $Ω = [0, 1].$ Suppose that a decision maker can choose
> to either be perfectly informed, so that she gets to know the exact value
> of $ω,$ or only be told if the true $ω$ is smaller or larger than $1/2.$ In the
> first case, the information can be modeled as the partition of all elements of
> $Ω,$ $τ = \{{ω} : ω ∈ Ω\}.$ In the second case, the information is the partition
> $τ' = \{[0, 1/2); [1/2, 1]\}.$
>
> Suppose we were to model the informational content of $τ$ and $τ'$ by the algebras generated by $τ$ and $τ'$; denote these by $A(τ) $ and $A(τ'). $It is easy to see that $A(τ') = \{∅; Ω; [0, 1/2); [1/2, 1]\}, $ while **$ A(τ)$ is the collection of sets in $[0, 1]$ that are either finite or have finite complement**.
> The first problem with algebras as a model of information is that $A(τ)$ is not finer than $A(τ'):$ a decision maker with information $A(τ') $may get to learn that the event $[0, 1/2) $has happened; a decision maker with information $A(τ ) $never learns if $[0, 1/2) $has happened or not because $[0, 1/2) \notin A(τ).$
> The second—and more important—problem with algebras as a model of information is that it can predict the wrong choice by a decision maker.

The sigma algebra generated by $\tau'$ is very easy to see; however, I don't understand the sigma algebra generated by $\tau:$ I presume that it can't be the power set of the real line between zero and one because that would not fit into the criteria of a sigma algebra, i.e. including singletons corresponding to each real number between $[0,1]$ is not a possibility. But this is exactly what the "state of the world" is - a real number between $0$ and $1.$ So what does this $\sigma(\tau)$ (I think that is expressed as $A(\tau)$ above) look like?

Comment: Frankly, I don't think it makes sense to compare these two sigma-algebras as finer or not finite. A sigma algebra $\mathscr{F}$ is finer than $\mathscr{G}$ if $\mathscr{G} \subset \mathscr{F}$, not just if one has larger or smaller cardinality than the other.

Comment: Of course, I haven't read the entire paper, so take what I say with a grain of salt.

Comment: @rubikscube09 That's interesting, but my problem is more basic: I have no clue what $\sigma(\tau)$ would look like.

Comment: I would assume that the sigma algebra would be sets that are countable, or either have countable complement: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782957/sigma-algebra-generated-by-the-set-of-all-singletons

Comment: Why is the power set not a sigma algebra? (it's not *this* one, of course, but you say it's not satisfying the definition...)

Comment: $A$ and $A’$ are just algebras, not sigma-algebras. (They’re closed under finite unions and intersections.)